# String Manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

How can I get the value between the `{}`  eg. `1` in `"{1}"` and use it?

Comment: I want to take off numbers between { and }.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/\{(\d+)\}/', $str, $mtch))
    echo $mtch[1];
```

where $str is '{1}'

Comment: by the way, you might wanna anchor that regex like this: /^\{(\d+)\}$/
It will make sure the string contains exactly that and it won't match for, let's say 'abcd{4}'

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get rid of the brackets, you may use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function

```
    $str = "{1}";
    $str = trim($str, "{}");
    echo $str;  //output: 1
```

EDIT: I removed the comma - "{}" is enough as the secont parameter for trim() (was "{,}" before the edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a preg_replace function to perform a regular expression.

What exactly do you need to do the string.

If you want to get a certain character of the string, `$str = '{1}'; $str[1]` will return the 2nd character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you actually have .. in the example above this would be enough:

```
$number = $string{1};
```

But i guess you need more something like

```
preg_match('/{([0-9]+)}/', $string, $matches);
$number = $matches[1];
```